How do I generate a file name for my report based on the project name?
I have Playwright tests that generate a junit report that is uploaded to Testrail. This works well for one browser.
Now I want to use multiple browsers. Testrail complains about "section duplicates" and no longer uploads the report. How do I fix this?
One idea would be to make a separate config for each browser with a project with the respective browser and a unique file name. e.g. junit-report-firefox.xml
Then start the run with --config.
Is there a more elegant way available? With a config where, for example, the file name of the report is based on the name of the project? If so, how do I do that?
const testRailOptions = {
    outputFile: `./test-results/junit-report-${howToAccessTheProjectNameHere}.xml`,
};


Where this piece of code located at? is it inside a test? inside config file? please add more code.

I solved it myself by using separate stages in the Jenkinsfile. Then the report file name can remain the same.
